# How can I easily make the back arrow in a horizontal flow diagram go below the elements instead of above?

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
        \centering
        \smartdiagram[flow diagram:horizontal]{
            Apply shampoo,
            Lather,
            Rinse           
        }
\end{document}
```

This results in:
[image]

Is there a *simple* way to make the arrow go along the bottom of the diagram using built-in functionality of smartdiagram, or will I have to start messing with TikZ and smartdiagram internals?

(It's just a convention, I know, but as an engineer I expect feedback diagrams to loop around the bottom.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to use `smartdiagram`, you can't do it natively, but you can add a simple Ti*k*Z picture with overlay. Be aware that this is not working on `standalone` documentclass, hence the `article` one here.

[image: SmartDiagram]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\begin{document}

    \smartdiagramset{module x sep=3, back arrow disabled,}
    \smartdiagramadd[flow diagram:horizontal]{Apply shampoo, Lather, Rinse}{}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \draw[additional item arrow type,color=red!50] (module3) -- ++(0,-1) -| (module1);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. Do you need shadowing of the nodes?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[n/.style={draw,rounded corners,top color=white,bottom color=#1,minimum height=12mm,minimum width=2cm}]  
\def\a{2.8}
\path
(0,0)   node[n=cyan!30] (L) {Lather}
(\a,0)  node[n=blue!30] (R) {Rinse}
(-\a,0) node[n=red!30,align=center] (A) {Apply\\shampoo}
;
\begin{scope}[>=stealth,line width=3pt]
\draw[->,cyan!50] (A)--(L);
\draw[->,blue!50] (L)--(R);
\draw[->,red!50] (R.south)--+(-90:.8)-|(A.south);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Update: with shadowing `node`s (also can be done with the `shadows` library)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
myshadow/.style={rounded corners,minimum height=12mm,minimum width=2cm},
n/.style={myshadow,draw=gray,thick,font=\sffamily,top color=white,bottom color=#1},
m/.style={myshadow,fill=gray!50,shift={(-45:.15)}}]  
\def\a{2.8}
\path
(0,0)   node[m]{} node[n=cyan!30] (L) {Lather} 
(\a,0)  node[m]{} node[n=blue!30] (R) {Rinse}
(-\a,0) node[m]{} node[n=red!30,align=center] (A) {Apply\\shampoo}
;
\begin{scope}[>=stealth,line width=3pt]
\draw[->,cyan!50] (A)--(L);
\draw[->,blue!50] (L)--(R);
\draw[->,red!50] (R.south)--+(-90:.8)-|(A.south);
\end{scope}
        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```